# A field for multiple recipients

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a field which in itself contains other elements. Something like sending messages to multiple users in a social network.
[image: Example]

I tried to explore the code, but it is too confusing. I would be grateful if someone will share his experience and materials.

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add Fields</button>
<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; 
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); 

    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ 
            x++; 
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); 
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/volya/pen/GjvYZk)

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: Where is your code or which code are you trying to explore?

Comment: Adding the code.
Explore tried facebook and not quite work out.
And I'm sorry, why cons?

Comment: you mean something like this: https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags

Comment: @madalinivascu Yes, it is, thank you very much for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for your case, I think it will work Tag-it. You can find out more on:
http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/

Enjoy.